# Convert scientific notation to decimal in C++

Tags: c++, decimal, scientific-notation

I want to be able to output in decimal and not scientific for all cases in my code.

If I have 122041e+08 then I want it to display as 122041000

If I have 4.6342571e+06 then I want it to display as 4634257.1

... and so on.

Using my code, the output for 4.6342571e+06 is 4634257.100000

```
void conversion(double counts)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << std::fixed << counts;
  std::cout << ss.str() << " MeV";
}
```

Can someone explain to me why it adds 0's to the end and if it's possible to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in your output string stream called [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/). You can use it to adjust the number of digits after the comma. It defaults to 6 and missing digits are filled up with 0s (hence the name fixed). In order to achieve `4634257.1` being displayed, set precision to 1:

```
void conversion(double counts)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss.precision(1);
  ss << std::fixed << counts;
  std::cout << ss.str() << " MeV";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/).

Comment: https://ideone.com/5CmObK see here scientific number is converting into normal float number by use of `std::fixed` rather than `std::setprecision`. I don't claim mine is right but I am telling you what I observing. I am new to `c++`;

Answer (score 0):

It adds the zeros because you've (unknowingly) asked for them.  The default precision is 6, and in fixed format, that means 6 digits after the decimal (regardless of how many before).  The precision has a different meaning according to the format being used for the output.  (Which doesn't sound very orthogonal, but works out well in practice, once you know what to expect.)